# Search pagination link redirecting to a link that doesn't work with pagination

Tags: pagination, search

I have my search set up with a page called 'search' and a template called 'searchpage.php'.

When I visit 'domain.com/search?s=term' the URL changes to 'domain.com/search/?s=term'

To solve this and make it work I used:

```
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'search', EP_ALL );
```

However, my pagination links im creating use a URL structure of:

```
'domain.com/search?s=term&paged=3'
```

WP changes this URL to:

```
'domain.com/search/page/3/?s=term'
```

Which still shows a search page but the pagination doesn't work as it would if it kept the normal paged=x.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

If your are using a custom template I assume you are using a custom loop so first populate $paged.

```
<?php $max_posts = get_option('posts_per_page '); ?>
<?php global $paged; ?>
<?php 
  if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
  elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
  else { $paged = 1; }  
?>
```

Then use $paged in your own loop;

```
  <?php $args = array('posts_per_page' => $max_posts,
                      'paged' => $paged ); ?>
  <?php $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>          
  <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>            
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>        
    <article>
      Your code here
    </article>      
    <?php endwhile ?>    
  <?php endif; ?>
```